# Submitting a post request but remain on the page using spring mvc

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a simple reset password form screen. When the user submits via the Recover button the page posts to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/accountmanagement/user/password_reset . In that endpoint the user's email is validated then a hash is generated that is concatenated into a link which is sent by the system to the user via email. Everything works fine, its just that, what I want to happen is when the user clicks the recover button, I want them to remain on the recover password page. What I plan to do is to just unhide a div saying "Thank you for submitting a recover your password request etc.". Showing the div is not a problem (might be using plain javascript -- I don't have a js framework -- maybe use jQuery), its just that when the user clicks the recover button, the post request goes to the rest api therefore changing the page that is being displayed.

I tried to add `target="_blank"` in the form, but it didn't work. My front end is written in html and thymeleaf only.

There might be a simple solution out there that I'm just missing.

resetPassword.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Reset Password</title>
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <div>
    <h2>Recover your password</h2>
    <p>To recover your password follow the instructions below to reset your password.</p>
  </div>

  <form th:action="@{/api/v1/accountmanagement/user/password_reset}" method="post"
        id="resetPasswordForm" th:object="${account}" target="_blank">
    <div id="field_email">
      <label for="email">Enter your email address :</label>
      <p>Enter the email address with your account.</p>
      <div><input type="text" id="email" name="email" th:field="*{email}"/></div>
    </div>

    <div id="successRecover" style="display: none;">
      An email has been sent to your email address. The email contains instructions to reset your password.
    </div>
    <div th:if="${param.error}" class="login-panel_error error">Error.</div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner hidden"></i>
        <span>Recover</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

PasswordManagementController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/accountmanagement")
public class PasswordManagementController {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordResetService passwordResetService;

    private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/password_reset", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity processResetPassword(@ModelAttribute(value = "account") Account account,
                                               BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
        LOG.info("account email " + account.getEmail());

        // build the hash here for hashUrl

        if (account != null) {
            if (!StringUtil.isBlank(account.getEmail())) {
                try {
                    passwordResetService.processResetPassword(account, hashUrl);
                } catch (AccountConfigException ace) {
                    // deal with exception here.
                    // return
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // deal with exception here.
                    // return
                }
                return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                // deal with an exception here.
                // return
            }
        } else {
            // deal with an exception here.
            // return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are submitting a page/form, consider using ajax to hit the server and when it returns response then using javascript hide/unhide the correct div.

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning a `ResponseEntity` in the case of a successful request you will indeed be redirected.
I don't know how you handle errors but what you might want to do is changing the return type of your controller method to `String`. This way you can redirect to the same page in case of a successful response while passing a `boolean` value to the model that will decide to render your `successRecover` div, without needing any Javascript.

The new handler:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/password_reset", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processResetPassword(@ModelAttribute(value = "account") Account account, Model model) {
    // build the hash here for hashUrl
    try {
        passwordResetService.processResetPassword(account, hashUrl);
    } catch (AccountConfigException ace) {
        // deal with exception here.
        // return
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // deal with exception here.
        // return
    }
    model.addAttribute("isOK", true);

    return "index";
}
```

And then in the view:

```
<div id="successRecover" th:if="${isOK}">
    An email has been sent to your email address. The email contains instructions to reset your password.
</div>
```